# Strange behaviour of localtime function

Tags: c++

I am trying to subtract 7 days from current date and send them to a function. My code is:

```
time_t startTime;
time_t endTime;
struct tm *startDate;
struct tm *endDate;

time(&endTime);
endDate = localtime(&endTime); //here endDate becomes 26-05-2015

startTime = endTime - 24 * 60 * 60 * 7;
startDate = localtime(&startTime);
```

however after this both endDate and startDate becomes 19-05-2015

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime :`Return value
1) pointer to a static internal tm object on success`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `localtime` is allowed to use an internal (`static`) buffer for the string, meaning you need to copy the string returned, or use [`localtime_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) instead.

Comment: I couldn't understand copy the string return. where should i copy?

Comment: @bhavesh Into a `tm` structure, e.g. `struct tm endDate = *localtime(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The [std::localtime()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) function returns a pointer to a static `struct` so it returns the same address each time.

You can make a copy of the return from [std::localtime()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) like this:

```
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    time_t startTime;
    time_t endTime;

    // don't use pointers
    std::tm startDate;
    std::tm endDate;

    time(&endTime);

    // dereference the return value (with *) to make a copy
    endDate = *std::localtime(&endTime); 

    startTime = endTime - 24 * 60 * 60 * 7;
    startDate = *std::localtime(&startTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are both pointers to the same structure. Declare your own `struct tm` variables and copy what the `localtime()` return value points to:

```
struct tm startDate, endDate;
....
endDate   = * localtime(&endTime);
....
startDate = * localtime(&startTime);
```